# Installing RasterIO with pyenv

Tags: python, gdal, pyenv, rasterio

RasterIO appears to be a very promising library for geospatial IO and much easier for me to navigate than gdal's python bindings. I am having trouble installing it correctly.

Currently, I have am using `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` to manage python distributions and environments, respectively. I installed gdal with brew using the following [steps](https://www.karambelkar.info/2016/10/gdal-2-on-mac-with-homebrew/).

I navigated to my project folder, activated the virtual environment and downloaded rasterio from PyPI: `pip install rasterio`. However, the only way to correctly import the package is to import `osgeo` first?!? I am concerned that this means I have some broken dependencies or I have installed `rasterio` incorrectly.

Specifically,

```
import osgeo
import rasterio
```

works fine (tested using with about half of their [quickstart](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/quickstart.html)), but

```
import rasterio
```

does not. The latter producing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Users/home/.pyenv/versions/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/home/.pyenv/versions/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CPLMalloc
    Referenced from: /Users/home/.pyenv/versions/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/home/.pyenv/versions/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Any suggestions on how to debug/interpret this error would be invaluable to me. Thanks!

If possible, I would prefer not build from source per these [instructions](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/wiki/GDAL-2.1-with-rasterio-on-OS-X).

Comment: You can save yourself some headache by using [conda / Anaconda / Miniconda](https://conda.io) for package management. As to your problem, I assume it is because `import osgeo` takes care of setting some environment variables that `rasterio` needs but that are not present in your virtualenv. Try Anaconda, @Charlie. `conda install rasterio -c conda-forge/label/dev`

Comment: I ended up doing the following:

1. uninstalling `gdal` with `brew` / uninstalling `rasterio` with `pip`
2. `brew update`
3. following the same installation instructions from above.

Worked fine - so I am happy. Happy to be able to automate `gdal` functions with `geojson` metadata.